# Completion of a $\sigma$-algebra is a $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

> Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ be a probability space. Let
>   \begin{align*}
>  \mathcal{N}&= \left\{N\subseteq\Omega:\exists F\in\mathcal{F}, N\subseteq F,\mathbb{P}(F)=0\right\}  \\ \mathcal{G}&=\left\{A\cup N:A\in\mathcal{F},N\in\mathcal{N}\right\} \end{align*}
>   Prove that $\mathcal{G}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.

I've shown that $\Omega\in\mathcal{G}$ and that if $(A_n)_n\subseteq\mathcal{G}$ then $\cup_n A_n\in\mathcal{G}$. How can I show that if $A\in\mathcal{G}$ then $A^c\in\mathcal{G}$?

I also noticed $\mathcal{F}\subseteq\mathcal{G}$ if it helps somehow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $G=A \cup N$ for $A \in \mathcal{F}$ and $N \in \mathcal{N}$. By definition, there exists $F \in \mathcal{F}$ such that $N \subseteq F$ and $\mathbb{P}(F)=0$.  Clearly,

$$G^c = A^c \cap N^c = \underbrace{A^c}_W \backslash \underbrace{(N \cap A^c)}_{U}$$

As $$\underbrace{N \cap A^c}_{U} \subseteq \underbrace{F \cap A^c}_{V} \subseteq \underbrace{A^c}_{W}$$ it follows that

$$G^c = \underbrace{\big(A^c \backslash (F \cap A^c)\big)}_{W \backslash V} \cup \underbrace{\big( (F \cap A^c) \backslash (N \cap A^c) \big)}_{V \backslash U}; \tag{1}$$

here we have used the general fact that

$$U \subseteq V \subseteq W \implies W \backslash U = (W \backslash V) \cup (V \backslash U).$$ Consequently, we have shown that

$$G^c = \tilde{A} \cup \tilde{N} \tag{2}$$

for

$$\tilde{A} := A^c \backslash (F \cap A^c)\quad \text{and} \quad \tilde{N}:= (F \cap A^c) \backslash (N \cap A^c).$$

As $\tilde{N} \subseteq F \in \mathcal{F}$ and $\mathbb{P}(F)=0$, we have $\tilde{N} \in \mathcal{N}$. Morover, $A \in \mathcal{F}$ and $F \in \mathcal{F}$ implies $\tilde{A} \in \mathcal{F}$. Consequently, $(2)$ shows that $G^c \in \mathcal{G}$.

Comment: Why is $(1)$ true? @saz

Comment: @J.Doe  It follows from the "general fact" which I stated directly afterwards.I've just rewritten it a bit... perhaps it's clearer now.

Answer (score 2):

Let $G$ be an event in $\mathcal G$, so we can write it in the form $G=A\cup N$ with $A\in\mathcal F$, $N\in\mathcal N$, so $N\subseteq F$, for some suitable $F\in \mathcal F$, $\Bbb P(F)=0$.

Then 
$$
\begin{aligned}
A &\subseteq {\color{red}{G}}=A\cup N\subseteq A\cup F\text{ leads to}\\
A^c &\supseteq {\color{red}{G^c}}=A^c\cap N^c\supseteq A^c\cap F^c\ ,
\end{aligned}
$$
so $G^c$ lies between two events in $\mathcal G$ that differ by a null set,
$$
0\le
\Bbb P(A^c-(A^c\cap F^c))
=
\Bbb P(A^c\cap F^{cc})
=
\Bbb P(A^c\cap F)
\le 
\Bbb P(F)
=0
\ .
$$

Comment: I got that $A^c\cap F^c\subseteq G^c\subseteq A^c$, but how does $\mathbb{P}(A^c\cap F)=0$ leads us to $G^c\in\mathcal{G}$? @dan_fulea

Comment: $G^c$ is then between $A_1:=A^c\cap F^c$ and $A_1\cup N_1$ for that $N_1$ that makes $A_1\cup N_1=A^c$.

Comment: Sorry for stubborning but I still don't get it.
We have $A_1=A^c\cap F^c\subseteq G^c\subseteq A^c=A_1\cup N_1$, but what does $G^c$ equal to for getting into the set $\mathcal{G}$? @dan_fulea

Comment: $G^c=A_1\cup\color{red}{(G^c-A_1)}$ and the red entry is a subset of $N_1$. Thanks for asking, please always ask, do not even hesitate to do it. It is then my fault of not finding the argument that hits the point...

Comment: We need that $G^c-A_1=(A^c\cap N^c)-(A^c\cap F^c)\in\mathcal{N}$. Why is that true? I observe that $G^c-A_1\subseteq A^c\cap N^c$ but not sure if it helps. @dan_fulea

Comment: @J.Doe $ G^c-A_1=(A^c \cap N^c) - (A^c \cap F^c)=(A^c \cap N^c) \cap (A^c \cap F^c)^c=(A^c \cap N^c) \cap (A\cup F) = (A^c\cap N^c \cap A)\cup (A^c \cap N^c \cap F) = (A^c \cap N^c \cap F)\subset F $

Answer (score 0):

> Lemma 1: $\cup_{i\in \mathbb{N}}F_i$ with $\mathbb{P}(F_i)=0$ is such that $\mathbb{P}(\cup_{i\in \mathbb{N}}F_i)=0$.

> Proof: Taking $F_i'=F_i\setminus(\cup_{j=1}^{i-1}F_i)$ it is easy to see these are disjoint and their union is invariant ($\cup_{i\in \mathbb{N}}F_i=\cup_{i\in \mathbb{N}}F_i'$). Hence: $$ \mathbb{P}(\cup_{i\in \mathbb{N}}F_i)=\mathbb{P}(\cup_{i\in \mathbb{N}}F_i')=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \mathbb{P}(F_i')\leq \sum_{i=1}^\infty \mathbb{P}(F_i)=0\quad \quad\square$$

> Lemma 2: An element is of the form  $A\cup N$ if and only if it can be writen as $(A\cup N_1 )\setminus N_2$

> Proof: Indeed, $A\cup N= (A\cup N)\setminus \emptyset$. For the other direction, we have $N_i\subset \hat{N_i}\in \mathcal{F}$ with $\mathbb{P}(\hat{N_i})=0$. With this notation in mind: $$(A\cup N_1)\cap N_2^C=(A\cap N_2^C)\cup (N_1 \cap N_2^C)$$ As $N_2\subset \hat{N}_2$, we have $\hat{N}_2^C\subset N_2^C$ and $A\cap N_2^C=(A\cap \hat{N}_2^C)\cup (A\cap N_2^C\cap \hat{N}_2)$. Therefore: $$(A\cup N_1)\cap N_2^C=(A\cap \hat{N}_2^C)\cup (A\cap N_2^C\cap \hat{N}_2)\cup (N_1 \cap N_2^C)$$ $A\cap \hat{N}_2^C\in \mathcal{F}$. On the other hand, the other two terms are contained in $\hat{N}_1\cup \hat{N_2}\in \mathcal{F}$. By our first result, $\mathbb{P}(\hat{N}_1\cup \hat{N_2})=0$. $\square$

All of the hard work is done and we need only apply Lemma's 1 and 2:

1. The emptyset and the entire set are clearly of the form $A\cup N$:

> Indeed $\emptyset= \emptyset \cup \emptyset$ and $X=X\cup \emptyset$

2. The complement of $(A\cup N_1)\setminus N_2$ is still of the same form

> $$((A\cup N_1)\setminus N_2 )^C= ((A\cap N_2^C)\cup (N_1\cap N_2^C))^C= (A^C \cup N_2)\setminus (N_1 \cap N_2^C)$$ The result follows because $A^C\in \mathcal{F}$, $N_1\cap N_2^C\subset \hat{N_1}$.

3. Countable union of the form $A\cup N $ is still of the same form:

> $$(\cup_{i\in \mathbb{N}}A_i)\cup (\cup_{i\in \mathbb{N}}N_i)$$ But $\cup_{i\in \mathbb{N}}A_i\in \mathcal{F}$, $\cup_{i\in \mathbb{N}} N_i \subset \cup_{i\in \mathbb{N}} \hat{N}_i \in \mathcal{F}$ and by Lemma 1, $\mathbb{P}(\cup_{i\in \mathbb{N}} \hat{N}_i) =0$